# How to get back data from NextActivity to CurrentActivity?

Tags: android

I have 2 activities FirstActivity, SecondActivity. MyActivities extending Activity. In my FirstActivity, there is a ExpandableListView containing childviews & groupviews. groupview containing 3textviews and 2 imageviews. Onclick of the firstImage i have to go to SecondActivity. In secondActivity, I can able to add some rows, and finally onclick of "done" button it should be back to FirstActivity along with the rows data that were added in SecondActivity and those SecondActivity rows should be added to a particular selected row in FirstActivity...

How should I do this...?

Can one please help me...

Comment: I've done tutorial in Bahasa Indonesia tha talk about sending and receiving data between Intent: http://bayu.freelancer.web.id/2012/05/29/cara-mengirim-data-antar-intent/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- use `startActivityForResult()` to start second Activity.
- And you will get result from second activity to first activity inside the `onActivityResult()` of first activity.

Comment: If we use onActivityResult, how should I to add data coming from SecondActivity present in onActivityResult to groupView of MyAdapter class?

Comment: can't you add data in adapter inside onActivityResult()? After adding data in adapter, don't forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Can u send me some sample examples? because I am very new to the android programming

Comment: wow....even though you have accepted answer. They why this request to me for example?

Comment: No that is correct thing to get the data from SecondActivity that I have done, thats why I accepted. But I am not sure how to add data present in onActivityResult to GroupView?

Answer (score 2):

in frist Activity start activiy as

```
startActivityForResult(this,YourscondActivity.class);
```

and in fristActivity override the menthod `onActivityResult()`. where you get the data of second activity.

in Second activity before finish set the result and add there data like

```
Intent i=new Intent();
i.putExtra("key ","your data"); and then
setResult(i);
secondActivity.finish();
```

this intent you get in firstActivity.

Answer (score 1):

use [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

to go from activity A to B ::

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUESTCODE);
```

From activty B, to send data to A ::

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra(KEY1, DataTosend1);
intent.putExtra(KEY2, DataTOSend2);

 finish();
```

again, Inside `onActivityResult()` of class A

```
  @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
     if(  requestCode == REQUESTCODE  )
     {
            ////////// use intent.get<Type>Extra(KEY) to receive data sent by B /////////

     }
}
```